# Differentiating Between Office 365 E3 From E1 Devices

Tags: microsoft-office

We are in the process of creating a report to determine all devices with Office 365 E3 installed.  Does anyone know if there's a version difference between E3, E1, and E5 that we can use to create a report on?

Any links or materials you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With Office 365 there's no such thing as "E1/E3/E5 installed". It's about licencing, and the desktop applications are exactly the same for E3/E5; the difference is in cloud services included, alone. E1 doesn't include desktop applications at all.

See https://products.office.com/en/business/compare-more-office-365-for-business-plans